# How do I define and instantiate a single instance of an anonymous inner class in a single expression

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, I want to add a "namespace" to a class that has a set of related functions. Clients of my class will use that namespace to help classify what type of operation they want to do. (I know you're thinking the functions should be in different classes, problem solved. But for other reasons, it's convenient to house all the functions in a single class).

So, I might have a class `Uber` that contains `fooInsert` `fooOpen` `fooDispose` along with `barInsert` `barTerminate` and `barHop`. As you can see there's no common interface. Just a bunch of functions that for some reason belong in the same class. Some have an affinity with others (i.e. the `fooXXX` functions "belong" together, as do the "barYYY" functions).

What I've come up with is:

```
class Uber {
  inner class FooNamespace {
    fun insert(): Unit {}
    fun open(): Unit {}
    fun dispose(): Unit {}
  }
  val foo = FooNamespace()

  inner class BarNamespace {
    fun insert(): Unit {}
    fun terminate(): Unit {}
    fun hop(): Unit {}
  }
  val bar = BarNamespace()
}
```

Users of the class can do something like this:

```
val uber = Uber()
uber.foo.insert()
uber.bar.hop()
```

What I'd like is something that combines the `inner class ...` and `val xxx = XxxNamespace()` into one expression. Something like:

```
// This doesn't actually compile
val foo = object: inner class {
    fun insert(): Unit {}
    fun open(): Unit {}
    fun dispose(): Unit {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you need a properly defined type if you to want to access these members publicly.

For private properties, the syntax `val foo = object { ... }` is sufficient, but for publicly exposed properties these are inferred as `Any` and it makes them unusable.

One option is obviously to define an interface for these types, but it's even more boilerplate than what you came up with already, so I am pretty sure this won't suit your needs:

```kotlin
interface FooNamespace {
    fun insert()
    fun open()
    fun dispose()
}

class Uber {
    val foo = object : FooNamespace {
        override fun insert(): Unit {}
        override fun open(): Unit {}
        override fun dispose(): Unit {}
    }
}
```

> I know you're thinking the functions should be in different classes, problem solved. But for other reasons, it's convenient to house all of the functions in a single class

I'm indeed really thinking that, and would love to hear more about what makes it so convenient to put everything in the same class :) Since the classes are `inner classes`, I'm assuming this has to do with accessing private state from `Uber`, but that could also be done by wrapping this private state into another class that's passed to foo and bar.

Comment: I ended up refactoring the class into separate classes. I didn't want to do that because having many "entry points" into the type system has a higher cognitive load for the developer. For context -- an `uber` was injected into the class, and from there they could type `uber.` and it would show `foo` and `bar` as options. Now they have to inject both a `Foo` and a `Bar` (and perhaps many other things).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not possible, at least for now.

The main technical problem here is that `uber.foo.insert()` is really interpreted as chaining `uber.foo` and then `.insert()`. So for this to work, `uber.foo` needs to have an explicitly defined type. It can't be anonymous class/object, because then there is no way to describe what is the type of `uber.foo`.

That being said, I've always wondered why Kotlin does not support this syntax:

```kotlin
val foo = object Foo {}
```

This is consistent with the object declaration where the name of the singleton is at the same time the name of the class. And the compiler even understands this above syntax, because it throws the error: "An object expression cannot bind a name". So Kotlin authors seem to intentionally disallow such use.

I found an issue in the YouTrack, so we can at least upvote it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21329

Comment: In that syntax, the object name is defined within the scope of the expression that initialized `foo` so I don’t think it should allow you to provide a name, since the name would either be useless, or break established behavior in this case.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I must admit, I didn't even try to look at this from the "language structure" perspective @Tenfour04

Comment: I'd say that moreover, naming this object would be wrong in terms of conventions. An object can have only one instance, but here you're defining as many `Foo` as there are `Uber` instances. So I think it must be forbidden.

Comment: @Joffrey Why only one instance? We speak about object expression here, not object declaration. If we use object expression inside a class, then it actually compiles to an inner class and we can use it as any other inner class - we can access outer class, its members, etc. The only thing we can't do is to give an explicit name to this class, so it can be referenced. Right now this class has to be anonymous, so the result of object expression is "untyped".

Comment: But after thinking about it a little I see @Tenfour04 has a really good point. Normally, named types aren't created implicitly - as a side-effect of some expression. They're always created explicitly by one of interface/class/object declarations. This syntax above would be an exception of this rule. Still, I would be happy to have such feature, I just don't know what would be the right syntax for it.

Comment: *We speak about object expression here, not object declaration* - I'm aware. What I mean is that the fact that this object expression would define a class name (`Outer.ObjectName`) makes a lot of difference. Usual object expressions have no name, so there is obviously a single instance in the whole app of this type, because even the type only exists for that object expression, and cannot be referenced anywhere. If it has a name, now this class would have several instances - one per `Outer` instance, and yet it would be declared as an `object`, which is inconsistent with every other `object`s.